# Non-blocking Sockets vs BeginXXX vs SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, nonblocking

Can anyone please enlighten me about current .NET socket techniques?

1. **Non-blocking sockets**

   If I set Socket.Blocking = false and use async operations - what will happen?

   Is there any method of polling multiple non-blocking sockets instead of checking them for availability one-by-one (something like trivial select() or any other mechanism, some IOCP-related may be) aside from Socket.Select()?
2. **BeginXXX and SocketAsyncEventArgs**

   Are they operating on blocking sockets under the hood and just hide thread creation?

   Will manual creation of threads be equal to using BeginXXX methods?

   Is there any other pros on using SocketAsyncEventArgs other then it allows to create pool of sockets and everything related to them?

And one final question: if app is working as some kind of heavily loaded binary proxy with most logic done in single thread - what provides better scalability: non-blocking approach or async operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: `Socket.Select` should do that, although I don't tend to use that approach personally; in particular those `IList` get annoying at high volumes

2: no, other way around; the blocking operations are essentially using the non-blocking in the background, but with gates. No, they don't create threads under the hood - unless you count the callback when something is inbound. I have an example here that is serving 12k connections using `SocketAsyncEventArgs` - the thread count is something like 20. Among the intentions of `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is that:

- it is far easier to pool effectively, without having lots of objects created/collected per operation
- you can handle the "data is available now" scenario very efficiently without needing a callback at all (if the method returns false, you are meant to process the data immediately - no callback will be forthcoming)

For scalability: async

Comment: I am more concerned about performance of Socket.Select() (dealing with lists not much harded then dealing with async code).

BeginXXX calls callbacks in other threads (so far I've seen). I guess SocketAsyncEventArgs simply provides mechanism for limiting this thread count explosion, so you won't get more then you actually expect, or am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed, BeginXXX calls back on another thread; the point in my last bullet actually helps reduce this a lot, allowing you to use the async API but react appropriately if the data is available now; for everything else: semaphores ;p

Comment: Main problem with SAEA for me is that it requires to handle right order of recv/send tasks so there won't be two async operations pending on one socket. And as most logic in my app runs in single thread (to avoid locks), I have to return control from async operations to this main thread

Comment: @Aquilae then you'll need some kind of buffer layer, so you have somewhere to put data even if the socket is already sending

Comment: Currently I have simple FIFO collection of tasks associated with each socket always with recv as it's last element, so they are dequeued only when current task is finished.
Thanks for idea though I'll see if buffer solution will improve performance

Comment: @Aquilae another approach: remove the busy sockets from your core loop - and only put them back when they have finished reading/writing

Comment: I know this question/comment is old, but is the statement "it requires to handle right order of recv/send tasks so there won't be two async operations pending on one socket" still true? I use SAEA with one pending recv and one pending send async operation at the same time and I didn't see any problems yet?

Comment: @R1PFake I could have phrased that better; you can't have more than one send, or more than one receive; you can have one of each concurrently, though